# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslClientContext

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor-netty, r2dbc

I am writing tests for flux streams and when I run the tests I get the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class.io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslClientContext. but when I check on the dependencies in the netty packages the class is there. This is only happening while running tests. below is my code and stack trace

```
    @DisplayName("Test findAll Success")
    void findAllTest() throws Exception {
        Flux<LimitAmounts> limits = utilSevice.fetchAmounts();
        StepVerifier.create(limits)
                .expectNextCount(15)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
    } 

2021-07-21 16:49:04.282 ERROR 101390 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] d.m.r.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient    : Error: Could not initialize class io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslClientContext

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslClientContext
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:824) ~[netty-handler-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:611) ~[netty-handler-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider.<init>(SslProvider.java:350) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$Build.build(SslProvider.java:734) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.SslBridgeHandler.buildProvider(SslBridgeHandler.java:161) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.SslBridgeHandler.handleSslState(SslBridgeHandler.java:135) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.SslBridgeHandler.userEventTriggered(SslBridgeHandler.java:86) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:332) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.userEventTriggered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1428) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:332) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireUserEventTriggered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:913) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.MessageDuplexCodec.write(MessageDuplexCodec.java:118) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:764) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:808) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1025) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:306) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.lambda$sendObject$2(ChannelOperations.java:309) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at reactor.netty.FutureMono$DeferredFutureMono.subscribe(FutureMono.java:115) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.netty.NettyOutbound.subscribe(NettyOutbound.java:337) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:448) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:250) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.onNext(EmitterProcessor.java:265) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient.lambda$null$7(ReactorNettyClient.java:174) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onNext(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:120) ~[spring-security-test-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.onNext(EmitterProcessor.java:265) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.InitHandler.accept(QueryFlow.java:605) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.InitHandler.accept(QueryFlow.java:545) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onNext(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:120) ~[spring-security-test-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.onNext(EmitterProcessor.java:265) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient$ResponseSink.next(ReactorNettyClient.java:340) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient.lambda$new$0(ReactorNettyClient.java:103) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:184) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:280) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:389) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:401) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:94) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.MessageDuplexCodec.handleDecoded(MessageDuplexCodec.java:187) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.MessageDuplexCodec.channelRead(MessageDuplexCodec.java:95) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.65.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.65.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.65.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

here is my db config bean

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class MyTestConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration{

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return MySqlConnectionFactory.from(MySqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .host(System.getenv("DATABASE_HOST"))
                .port(3306)
                .user(System.getenv("DATABASE_USER"))
                .password(System.getenv("DATABASE_PASS"))
                .sslMode(SslMode.DISABLED)
                .build());
    }
    
}
```

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rx</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>rxApi</name>
    <description>Reactive version of my api</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <type>module</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.miku</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId> <!-- or jjwt-gson if Gson is preferred -->
            <version>0.11.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
            <version>8.12.12</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-rabbitmq</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>blockhound-junit-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your pom.xml

Comment: @Toerktumlare added

Comment: why have you defined a different version of the actuator than the parent pom? please omit all version numbers related to spring dependencies so that the parent pom decides the version. <version>2.4.5</version>

Comment: removed all of them still getting same error

Comment: Then please produce a small reproducible example since i cant reproduce this.

Comment: https://github.com/martinkimani/fluxtest2

check that one out. i haven't changed the pom for the original project

Comment: Can you try Spring Boot 2.5.3 just in case it is not something already fixed?

Comment: still doesnt work even with springboot 2.5.3